# how to align the table td contents on the same line with floating elements?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

In `td` I am using two content-text one is containing with red border and the second without border.

I want to make it in one line without line break and I have already used the css `style="nowrap"` it working and aligned content on the same but as I apply the first element with `float left` and second `float right` the second content shifted to the new line. But I want on the same line .
I have set the `td width :auto`.

below is my code:

```css
td,
th {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td .leftspanTagStyle {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

td .rightspanTagStyle {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<td class="greencolor" align="right">
  <span class="leftspanTagStyle">   1022221101 1,022,221,101 1,022,221,1,022,221,101 1,022,221,1,022,221,101 1,022,221,1,022,221,</span>
  <span class="CommaSeparated rightspanTagStyle"><b>256256</b></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Forgot to put dot before class while writing code on stack but the issue remain the same

Comment: you still should provide enough code to reproduce the issue. With the code you provided I can not reproduce the issue at all: However I would recommend not to use float for stylign purpose in the first place.